# Liquidity Solution for Crypo Exchanges

Tags: client, api, buy-bitcoins, decentralized-exchanges, exchange-software

I need to connect to a network of global crypto-exchanges and shares their order books (DSO Liquidity Solution) so ensures that right from the very start my client exchange software will have a full and healthy order book, allowing users to buy and sell against all other users on the DSO network.

can anyone suggest me a DSO API or any other Liquidity Solution with a fair price and good documentation?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Amin, were you able to find a solution? Please provide the links.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal I don't find a firm solution yet, but i will post my comment if i find a finite solution for this.